# git lab ci service connection refused

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I have a docker image listed in my gitlab ci services list. When I make an htpp request using curl to my docker service url everything works fine. But when I run my tests which makes an http request using axios to the service docker image url it says connection refused here is the exact message `connect EINVAL 0.0.31.129:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that I was using a service on my registry running on specific port and the runner was trying to connect to the registry at port 80. Because since I did specify the port the runner don't exactly know what protocol to use. So, the runner pick default port for http which is 80. So, the fix will be to add http protocol to the registry url.